# Should I avoid Di when classes are testable with black box testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd

I'm implementing something similar to nand2tetris project except I write all my code in java not using HDL and I'm writing tests on my own. 
For problem ilustration:
I have implemented nand logic gate which will be dependency to OR, AND, XOR and NOT logic gates.

I have doubt on these two approaches:

1) DI approach

```
public interface Nand {
  int nand(int a, int b);
}

public class NandImpl implements Nand {
  public int nand(int a, int b) {
    return a * b == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  }
}

public interface And {
  int and(int a, int b);
}

public class AndImpl implements And {
  Nand nand;

  public AndImpl(Nand nand) {
    this.nand = nand;
  }

  public int and(int a, int b) {
    return nand.nand(nand.nand(a, b), nand.nand(a, b));
  }
}
```

2) Approach without DI

```
public class NandImpl {

  static NandImpl singleton = null;

  protected NandImpl() {
  }

  public static NandImpl getInstance() {
    if(singleton == null) {
      singleton = new NandImpl();
    }
    return singleton;
  }

  public int nand(int a, int b) {
    return a * b == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  }
}

public class AndImpl {

  static AndImpl singleton = null;
  NandImpl nand;

  protected AndImpl() {
    nand = NandImpl.getInstance();
  }

  public static AndImpl getInstance() {
    if(singleton == null) {
      singleton = new AndImpl();
    }
    return singleton;
  }

  public int and(int a, int b) {
    return nand.nand(nand.nand(a, b), nand.nand(a, b));
  }
}
```

I started with aproach under 1) but I'm now in a doubt since I always need to stub dependencies in test to have real implementations which somehow seems wrong to me.
Also I don't see any advantage on DI here since I can fully test AND, OR, NOT and XOR implementations with truth tables.

Which way should I prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about how you use an actual logic gate.

You normally have two inputs, one output, and a black box between. It doesn't matter whether it's a NAND, AND, OR or anything else - the interface looks identical. All logic gates look the same. If you have a circuit which takes different logic gates, you could plug any of them into it and get different behaviour.

Your interface naming is therefore part of the problem. This isn't a NAND or AND with an implementation, it's a LogicGate which can be implemented as a NAND or AND.

If you do that, it also becomes obvious that the AND gate can't just rely on the implementation of whatever gets passed to it. It needs either actual NAND gates, or some other way of making it work.

DI is appropriate when the thing using its collaborators can trust them completely, and doesn't need to know about their implementation. That isn't the case here - and there might be other ways of getting the AND gate to work - so don't use DI.

If there's anything which uses a logic gate without caring about its implementation - just trusting that it's doing the appropriate job, whatever it happens to be at the time - *then* you can use DI.